# Android - swipe and rotate animation of ImageView from right to left

Tags: android, android-animation

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:rotation="15"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_swipe"
        app:tint="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the image is aligned right inside RelativeLayout and rotated by 15

I want it to slide to the left of the parent and rotate to -15 while sliding.

The ImageView is a hand that is pointing up so it suppose to be a swipe animation from right to left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
swipe.animate().rotationBy(-30).setDuration(1000).translationX(-64).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

This is just off the top of my head but something like that should work! Might need to tweak the -64 value :)

Comment: Rotation works but I also need the image to slide to the left side while rotating :D It should end aligned left to the parent

Comment: Maybe you can give the relative layout an id, and then say `translationX(relativeLayout.left);` or like I say, just tweak the `-64` until it aligns

Comment: Ah ok I didn't understand what translationX stands for first, thanks :D

Comment: No problem. Yeah it's just moving the view left and right (along the X axis). TranslationY  will move it up and down. :)